# Access NSMutableDictionary values in Interface Builder

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, interface-builder, nsmutabledictionary

I thought this would be simple but after 2 days I'm admitting defeat.
The task is simple:
In the user interface, display & edit a single NSString value from a Key/Value pair contained in an NSMutableDictionary in myClass.

Here are the code extracts:
`myClass:

NSMutableDictionary *settings;

settings = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

[settings setObject:@"2400" forKey:@"test"];`
In IB:
- File's Owner Class = myClass
- NSDictionaryController Content Dictionary bound to File's Owner Model Key Path 'settings'
- NSTextField bound to DictionaryController arrangedObjects Model Key Path 'test'

**Produces the error:**
`[<_NSControllerKeyValuePair 0x1001db3d0> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key test.`

Any comments and help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure this has anything to do with IB. It does not look like you initialized your NSMutableDictionary. Try:

```
NSMutableDictionary *settings= [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithCapacity:10];
[settings setObject:@"2400" forKey:@"test"];
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Sorry, initialisation is done, I just forgot to include it in the code above.